# i have a problem to run in react-native by react-native-cli

Tags: react-native

Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object:
`org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated. unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}api-level> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}vendor>,<{}codename>,<{}abi>,<{}api-level>,<{}tag> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}vendor>,<{}codename>,<{}abi>,<{}api-level>,<{}tag> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}vendor>,<{}codename>,<{}abi>,<{}api-level>,<{}tag> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level> Errors limit exceeded. To receive all errors set com.sun.xml.bind logger to FINEST level. unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}api-level> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 in C:\Users\taha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 accepted. Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a warning of AGP which is outside our control. It is safe to ignore this warning. There are some changes in Gradle internals that are causing this check in AGP to fail. It got fixed in AGP 7.1 (and versions afterwards) so it will go away in RN 0.69.
For the time being you're fine discarding this warning.